# Images that use image Rendition are not getting cached

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, image-rendition

I am using image renditions for rendering images of various sizes

When i check the network, it shows that the images that are from **PublishingImages** (images that use image Rendition) are having an http status of **304** (other images from other places like style library etc are having 200)

The other images are being loaded from cache where as images that use image rendering i.e `...../ImageName?RenditionID=x` are not loaded from cache

Is there a way where i can use cache for these images too?

I have read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2012/08/29/blob-cache-in-sharepoint.aspx), [this](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/05/optimization-blob-caching-and-http-304s.html) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4a88afc6-0f54-420b-8729-85b536537a72/sharepoint-2010-cache-not-working-for-publishing-images-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Comment: when you visit the image rendition page from site settings, is their any error?

Comment: also try to flush the blob cache https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg277249.aspx

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE No I dont get any errors!!

Comment: did you flush the blob cache?

Comment: yeah @WaqasSarwarMCSE tried that

is it possible to make status of images from PublishingImages folder to 200?

Comment: what is the image type i.e.gif jpg etc? is it different type then othe rimages who loaded from cache...

Comment: No there is no difference except that the image is loaded from PublishingImages folder which will use imagerendition

Comment: how many images having this issue? may be try to delete them and re upload

Comment: all the images from the publishingImages folder have this issue !! 
even newly uploaded images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24911/discussion-between-vignesh-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).

Comment: did you enable the image rendition on the site?

Comment: Yeah, we are having images in PublishingImages only for that reason
Can we enable Image rendition in Style Library?

Comment: i dont think, you just need to set it from Site setting under look and feel > image rendition....try this path and see what is enabled http://sote/_catalogs/masterpage/PublishingImageRenditions.xml

Comment: even images from style library give status of 304 if i use rendition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images in Publishing Library should be published to enabled caching.  If not, the the image response will include 304, which will need to go back to the server to check if the image has changed.  Though 304 requests are served from browser cache, it still has to take a roundtrip to server to confirm the image has not changed.

Hope it helps.